# What is the name of a number that does not have repeating prime factor

Tags: terminology, prime-factorization

For example, $10$ does not have repeating prime factor, $2$ and $5$, while $20$ have repeating prime factor, $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5$. What is the name of number that does not have repeating prime factor? I tried searching on google but does not found the name.

Comment: Square-free …..

Comment: square-free , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer

Comment: A number for which $\mu(n)=1$ where $\mu$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)

Comment: Alternatively : Quadratfrei [[ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Quadratfrei.html ]] which is a "Cooler" sounding Synonym.

Comment: "quadratfrei" is just the german name for "squarefree" , I do not think that it is usually used in an English written mathematical text.